# Is there a Google Insights API?

Tags: python, api

I've been looking for an API to automatically retrieve Google Insights information for part of another algorithm, but have been unable to find anything. The first result on Google delivers a site with a python plugin which is now out of date.

Does such an API exist, or has anyone written a plugin, perhaps for python?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no API available as of yet, and neither is there a working implementation of a method for extracting data from Google Insights. However, I have found a solution to my (slightly more specific) problem, which could really just be solved by knowing how many times certain terms are searched for.

This can be done by interfacing with the Google Suggest protocol for webbrowser search bars. When you give it a word, it returns a list of suggested phrases as well as the number of times each phase has been searched (I'm not sure about the time unit, presumably in the last year).

Here is some python code for doing this, slightly adapted from code by odewahn1 at [O'reilly Answers](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1526-how-to-use-the-google-suggest-api-to-come-up-with-topics-for-answers/) and working on Python 2.6 and lower:

```
from sgmllib import SGMLParser
import urllib2
import urllib

# Define the class that will parse the suggestion XML
class PullSuggestions(SGMLParser):

   def reset(self):
      SGMLParser.reset(self)
      self.suggestions = []
      self.queries = []

   def start_suggestion(self, attrs):
      for a in attrs:
         if a[0] == 'data': self.suggestions.append(a[1])

   def start_num_queries(self, attrs):
      for a in attrs:
         if a[0] == 'int': self.queries.append(a[1])

# ENTER THE BASE QUERY HERE

base_query = ""  #This is the base query

base_query += "%s"
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
for letter in alphabet:
   q = base_query % letter;
   query = urllib.urlencode({'q' : q})
   url = "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&%s" % query

   res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
   parser = PullSuggestions()
   parser.feed(res.read())
   parser.close()

   for i in range(0,len(parser.suggestions)):
      print "%s\t%s" % (parser.suggestions[i], parser.queries[i])
```

This at least solves the problem in part, but unfortunately it is still difficult to reliably obtain the number of searches for any specific word or phrase and impossible to obtain the search history of different phrases.

Comment: It appears that they got rid of the int attribute. If I got to "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=hello%20world" it just has the data attribute now.

Comment: I was wondering if there is still no related official API available currently (2014). Searched for a while but didn't find anything yet.

Answer (score 2):

I just started searching for it and found a good way to retrieve it using python in the following [script](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/econpy/5106304).Basically it is passing specialized quote to google historical financial database.

```
def get_index(gindex, startdate=20040101):
    """
    API wrapper for Google Domestic Trends data.
        https://www.google.com/finance/domestic_trends

    Available Indices:

       'ADVERT', 'AIRTVL', 'AUTOBY', 'AUTOFI', 'AUTO', 'BIZIND', 'BNKRPT',
       'COMLND', 'COMPUT', 'CONSTR', 'CRCARD', 'DURBLE', 'EDUCAT', 'INVEST',
       'FINPLN', 'FURNTR', 'INSUR', 'JOBS', 'LUXURY', 'MOBILE', 'MTGE',
       'RLEST', 'RENTAL', 'SHOP', 'TRAVEL', 'UNEMPL'

    """
    base_url = 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=GOOGLEINDEX_US:'
    full_url = '%s%s&output=csv&startdate=%s' % (base_url, gindex, startdate)
    dframe = read_csv(urlopen(full_url), index_col=0)
    dframe.index = DatetimeIndex(dframe.index)
    dframe = dframe.sort_index(0)
    for col in dframe.columns:
        if len(dframe[col].unique()) == 1:
            dframe.pop(col)
    if len(dframe.columns) == 1 and dframe.columns[0] == 'Close':
        dframe.columns = [gindex]
    return dframe[gindex]
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any documentation provided by Google, but Brad Jasper seems to have come up with some method for querying Insights for information. Note: I'm not sure if it still works... Good luck!

[Use Python to Access Google Insights API](http://bradjasper.com/blog/use-python-to-access-google-insights-api.html)

Comment: Yes, that would be the one I referred to in my question. Unfortunately, it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no, however the [Google Adwords API Keyword Estimator](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/latest/TrafficEstimatorService.KeywordEstimateRequest) may solve your need